# Angular Material 2 : How to style an md-grid-tile?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

```
 <md-grid-list cols="3" >
  <md-grid-tile style="overflow : scroll;align-items: initial;">

    <app-general style="padding-left : 1em;" ></app-general>

  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile class="dummy" style="overflow : scroll;align-items: initial;">
    <app-slab2g style="padding-left : 1em;" > </app-slab2g>

  </md-grid-tile>

  <md-grid-tile style="overflow : scroll;align-items: initial;">
    <app-slab3g style="padding-left : 1em;" > </app-slab3g>


  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

How to align items inside the md-grid-tile differently other than its default center alignment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `::ng-deep` to override the default css of `md-grid-tile`.

css:

```
::ng-deep md-grid-tile.mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
    align-items: initial;  /*vertical alignment*/
    justify-content: initial;  /*horizontal alignment*/
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bSD3en761PHxYusGIg9j?p=preview)

Comment: yea but this messes up other places you use grid-tiles.

Comment: Yes , i noticed it later too . But i found another fix as well . Might , Post it after sometime

Comment: Set the styles globlally in the styles.css / styles.sccs file like so:
`mat-grid-tile.yourClass{
overflow:auto
}` since `::ng-deep`is deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 6):

After much blood and tears, I was able to style the first column of an angular material grid without affecting other grids on the page.  The below style will left align and center vertically the Persons Name only in this `<mat-grid-list>`.

Angular material grid:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="4:1">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2">
        <div class="leftVerticalAlign">
        Persons Name
        </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>Persons Phone</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile [style.border-left]="'12px solid gray'">Persons Email</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

The elusive CSS:

```
.leftVerticalAlign {
    left: 1em;    
    position: absolute;  
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0px, -50%);
    margin: 0;
}
```

I threw an extra `border-left` style in there as another way to apply styles, but it's limited to what it can style I've noticed.

For more info about aligning horizontally and vertically check out [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

They saved my life on this one.

Comment: The one and only solution I could find that still works with Angular version 14.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid messing with your whole project, use in the component:

HTML:

`<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="8" class="script-menu">    </mat-grid-tile>`

CSS:

```
.script-menu >::ng-deep .mat-figure{
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: try using :host , to keep the scope as the component itself and not leak the styles defined by ng-deep outside the component

Comment: Good advice! @AakashUniyal

Answer (score 4):

html

```
<mat-grid-tile class="title-tem">
  <div class="item-content">
    hi
  </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

css

```
 .title-tem >::ng-deep .mat-figure{
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

that will be work :)

Answer (score 3):

this is the only reliable solution I found so far. !important didn't work. ::ng-deep messes up main code. If you use div and use absolute in css you can align the div the way you want.

html

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let project of projects" 
        [style.background]="project.Color" (click)="openDialog(project)" >
        <div fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="footer">

        </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

css

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[::ng-deep is deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), don't use it.
based on [Customizing Angular Material component styles](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles), by default, you cannot override the styles affect elements that are children of other components within your template.
One practice is:

```
.your-component .mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```